# How to sort models by an associated model's created_at date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given:

> A Company `has_many :customers`
>
> A Customer `has_many :messages`

I want to sort a list of customers by the `created_at` date of their last message sent. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know is by [merging scopes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge):

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages

  scope :by_most_recent_message, -> {
    joins(:messages).merge(Message.by_most_recent)
  }
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_most_recent, -> { order(:created_at).reverse_order }
end
```

Then you can call `company.customers.by_most_recent_message`.

Comment: By using `joins` you will get duplicate customers (one for each message). Use `includes` instead.